# Use Selenium to retrieve Backlink, HTTP code and IP address

Tags: curl, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im using Selenium to 'scrap' pages looking for backlinks to my website. I had been using plain curl to scrape however curl doesn't play nice with JavaScript (in fact they wont play at all).

My issue is that I need the HTTP header response (200, 301, 404, 503 etc) code from the pages I scrape. Ideally Id like to get the IP address of the domain I'm scraping as well.

Im using the facebook php webdriver for PHP at the following link and I cannot find how I could retrieve any header information.

https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver

My question is, is there a way to get Selenium to return header information and or an IP address?

If you don't know the answer to that question then do you know of a better way to scrape and or get HTTP headers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium doesn't do HTTP status codes or headers.  I've never used it, but the commonly-suggested tool is the [BrowserMob proxy](http://opensource.webmetrics.com/browsermob-proxy/), created by one of the Selenium committers.  It captures requests and responses, including headers, status codes, and timing information.